# Image change horrible when change page background

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I have one page in my project, this page will change background Property to random image in my assets when user touch in screen, but when change, page background change to black or white 0.05 second before change to my image. It's so ugly.

Here are my code in cs file

```
private void LayoutRoot_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Random ran = new Random();
        randomPage.Background = new ImageBrush
        {
            ImageSource =
                new BitmapImage { UriSource = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Backgrounds/" + ran.Next(22) + ".jpg") }
        };

        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

What can I do to change image page background smooth?

Comment: Could you create a short animation to fade the image to 0% opacity, switch the image, and then back to 100%?

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `StoryBoard` animation instead.

Example code to animate an `Image`

```
<Image  Stretch="Uniform" Name="myImage" Source="/Images/w1.png" />

<Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard1">
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.Source)"  Storyboard.TargetName="myImage" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="="/Images/w1.png"></DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="="/Images/w2.png"></DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="="/Images/w3.png"></DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="="/Images/w4.png"></DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4" Value="="/Images/w5.png"></DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>

Storyboard1.Begin();
```

---

In your case you probably want to create the `StoryBoard` in the code-behind and set up your random properties.  You can even "ease" the animation from one frame to another so smooth out the display.

Comment: @BoltDelta search StoryBoard for runtime and change the code around to fit, it's almost the same.

Comment: Thank you. I already solve my problem with FlipView, I don't know it before :D